# No such file or directory: '/kaggle/input/flickr8k/Images' i am getting this error while making a image caption generator

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, lstm

```
# extract features from image
features = {}
directory = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Images')

for img_name in tqdm(os.listdir(directory)):
    # load the image from file
    img_path = directory + '/' + img_name
    image = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    # convert image pixels to numpy array
    image = img_to_array(image)
    # reshape data for model
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
    # preprocess image for vgg
    image = preprocess_input(image)
    # extract features
    feature = model.predict(image, verbose=0)
    # get image ID
    image_id = img_name.split('.')[0]
    # store feature
    features[image_id] = feature
```

here is my code i have saved the flicker datset but getting this error no such file or directory error[2]

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: what is `BASE_DIR` ? it is not defined...